# How to restore remote MongoDB server with local mongodump data

Tags: mongodb, scp

We have a remote MongoDB server and we have mongodump data on a local developer's machine. What is the best way to restore the remote MongoDB server data with the local data? Is there a mongo command that we can use?

Comment: You could take a look at mongoexport, mongoimport to do this task

Comment: yeah we used mongorestore, because the original data dump was done using mongodump

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alright so we did this in two steps. I think you can do it in one step, with just `mongorestore`.

First we moved the data from the local machine to the remote machine with the `scp` command:

```
scp <path-to-mongofile> <remote-host>:<absolute-file-path>
```

then we ssh'd into the remote mongod server, and used mongorestore to restore the db

```
mongorestore --host=$HOST --port=$PORT -u $ADMIN_USER -p $PSWD  --db <your-db> <absolute-path-to-restore-db> --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

but I think the first `scp` command is redundant. In fact, if you cannot `ssh` into the server running `mongod`, then you will have to use the `mongorestore` command directly from the local developer's machine.

Comment: Hey Alexander! Sorry to bother you there but it seems that you did exactly what I'm looking for. I have absolutely no knowledge about SSH (I configured a raspberry pi server this morning for the first time) and I'd like to make a mongodump locally to restore it on my raspberry server. Would your solution work for me? Thanks!

Comment: Hey not 100% certain, but I think it would work :) Like I said in the answer, I think the scp command is redundant, try using the mongorestore command first. You have a mongod process running on the raspberry pi device right? My opinion, btw, is that SQLite3 might be a better db, if you have a choice.

Comment: yes, the ```scp``` command can be ommited. what worked for me is just running the mongorestore command from my dump folder this way: ```mongorestore --host=<host-name> --db <db-name> ./```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `mongorestore` but point it towards the remote server, such as:

`$ mongorestore -h ds01234567.mlab.com:12345 -d heroku_fj33kf -u <user> -p <password> <input db directory>`

From MongoLab's docs

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, can you send me the link to the exact command from the MongoDB docs? I cannot find it.